# How to display the data of DataProvider used in Amcharts graphics under each graph?

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I used Amcharts to make some graphics. I want to display under each graph its table of data (dataProvider) in my HTML page. I looked everywhere possible for a solution but in vain. Here is the table of data online on the amcharts website that I want to display

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example on how to automatically generate a table on AmCharts' website [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-create-a-table-of-chart-data-on-load/). This is the code from the example that you need to  add this code prior to your makeChart call:

```
/**
 * A plugin to automatically creata a data table for the chart
 * The plugin will check if the chart config has the following setting set: "dataTableId"
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  // check if export to table is enabled
  if (chart.dataTableId === undefined)
    return;

  // get chart data
  var data = chart.dataProvider;

  // create a table
  var holder = document.getElementById(chart.dataTableId);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  holder.appendChild(table);
  var tr, td;

  // add first row
  for (var x = 0; x < chart.dataProvider.length; x++) {
    // first row
    if (x == 0) {
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      table.appendChild(tr);
      td = document.createElement("th");
      td.innerHTML = chart.categoryAxis.title;
      tr.appendChild(td);
      for (var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
        td = document.createElement('th');
        td.innerHTML = chart.graphs[i].title;
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    }

    // add rows
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(tr);
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.className = "row-title";
    td.innerHTML = chart.dataProvider[x][chart.categoryField];
    tr.appendChild(td);
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = chart.dataProvider[x][chart.graphs[i].valueField];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

}, ["serial"]);
```

FYI, this code won't work in the live editor from your screenshot, in case you're using that to create your charts. You'll have to export the code and insert it there.

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for thank you !